The from address keeps changing to an unknown address when I sign my transaction - web3.js
I need help with something. I am trying to create a transaction, sign it, and send the transaction with web3, but every time it gets signed, the from address changes to a random address.
After much evaluation and testing on my wallet without including the private key, I realized it only works when nonce is zero. But whenever it is a higher nonce such as 54, it generates a random from wallet address.
import Transaction from "ethereumjs-tx";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const hashTx = (hash: any) => {
  const tx = new Transaction(hash);
  return tx;
};

  await web3.eth
    .getTransactionCount(target, "pending")
    .then(async (nonce1: any) => {
      const gasPrice: bigint = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
      const gasLimit: bigint = 22000n;
      const txFee: bigint = BigInt(Math.floor(Number(gasPrice) * 1.666));
      const funds: bigint = BigInt(10000000000000000n - txFee * gasLimit);
      const chainId: bigint = await web3.eth.getChainId();
      const minEth: bigint = 1000000000000000n;

      if (getBalance > minEth && getBalance > txFee && host) {
        const tx_ = {
          from: myAddr,
          to: host,
          nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce1),
          gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000n), // gasLimit
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(txFee),
          value: web3.utils.toHex(funds),
          data: "0x",
          v: "0x1", // original
          r: "0x",
          s: "0x",
        };

        const tx = hashTx(tx_);
        const serializedTx = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex");
        const sha3_: string = web3.utils.sha3(serializedTx)!;
        console.log("rawTx1:", serializedTx);
        console.log("rawHash1:", sha3_);

        await web3.eth
          .sign(sha3_, target)
          .then(async (signed: any) => {
            const temporary = signed.substring(2),
              r_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(0, 64),
              s_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(64, 128),
              rhema = parseInt(temporary.substring(128, 130), 16),
              v_ = web3.utils.toHex(rhema + Number(chainId) * 2 + 8);

            console.log("r:", r_);
            console.log("s:", s_);
            console.log("y:", v_);

            tx.r = r_;
            tx.s = s_;
            tx.v = v_;

            console.log(tx);
            console.log("---------------------------------------------");

            const txFin = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex"); //,
            const sha3__ = web3.utils.sha3(txFin);

            console.log("rawTx:", txFin);
            console.log("rawHash:", sha3__);

            await web3.eth
              .sendSignedTransaction(txFin)
              .then((elisebeth: any) => {
                console.log(elisebeth);
                toast.success("Successful Attempt");
              })
              .catch((vannette: any) => {
                console.log(vannette)
              });
          })
          .catch((heide: any) => {
            toast.error("Failed To Process Request");
            console.log(heide);
          });
      } else {
        toast.error("Doesn't Meet Requirements.");
      }

After every hashing process, gives and insufficient balance prompt.
I expect the transaction raw hash to use the signer public address as the from address, and not any random address. Also I want to use the RVS signature in replace of the private key, for research purposes.
But it does work when the nonce is zero but any other nonce value produce are wrong transaction.
